# How to invoke GNU gettext() with arguments?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, internationalization

I am implementing i18n to my project in c++ using GNU xgettext, Xcode.

The situation is as follows

FileOne.cpp

```
 void somefunction()
 { 
     string file = “fileName";
     loggerClass.addlog(gettext_args(“some %s missing “, file));
 }
```

FileTwo.cpp

```
 void someOtherfunction()
 { 
     string doc = “docName";
     loggerClass.addlog(gettext_args(“some %s missing “, doc));
 }
```

FileThree.cpp

```
std::string gettext_args(const std::string& format, Args ...args)
{        
    return string_format(gettext(format.c_str(), args…));
}
```

Since each file do not have explicit gettext() function call, I could not invoke xgettext for individual files (like: `xgettext -d FileOne -o FileOne.pot FileOne.cpp`) for this situation.

How should I invoke xgettext for a whole project (probably from Xcode)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read `xgettext`'s manual page, yet, and if not why not? `xgettext`'s manual page explains which option to pass to `xgettext`, in order for it to recognize that, say, for example, the first parameter to `gettext_args()` is a string that should be internationalized?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem here is if i run xgettext to extract strings from command line, it expects that all the .cpp files should have a gettext() function call. since there is no direct get text() call from FileOne.cpp and FileTwo.cpp it does not create .pot file for them. I guess I cannot use as it explained in that manual.

Comment: `xgettext`'s manual page explains which option to pass to `xgettext` so it would recognize that, for example, `gettext_args()`'s first argument is a string. I can assure you that after reading the manual page, I have no problems running `xgettext` on a file that doesn't have any calls to gettext(), and yet, somehow,`xgettext` finds all the right strings.

Comment: do you mean it is still possible to invoke xgettext from command line like(xgettext -d FileOne -o FileOne.pot FileOne.cpp) this?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter how one invokes xgettext, manually or from a script. It works the same way.

Comment: Thanks, after referred the manual, I tried to invoke xgettext like this  “xgettext -o language.pot   -f files.txt”  where files.txt contains list of .cpp files. But it does not extract the strings coming thru gettext_args() method.

Comment: In  debug the gettext method is called and assigns id to the incoming strings.  I assume that xgettext only scans the files for gettext() method call, if it sees it creates pot file and make an entry for the string in it. Is it right?

Comment: The call should be something like `xgettext --keyword=gettext_args -d FileOne -o FileOne.pot FileOne.cpp`

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42 , http://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik.

Answer (score -1):

You should read the [gettext documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#xgettext-Invocation) which also includes the information about this tool.